# read file, matching string (heading) and save block below each heading

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I know how to read a file line by line in python and if the case, match cases and save info in a dictionary. but now I have a txt file like this

```
Head 1 

bla1
bla2
bla3

Head 2

blo 1
blo 2
blo 3
blo 4

Head 3

blu 1
blu 2
```

and I need to save the informacion belonging to each head X for example like this

```
head 1 : {bla 1,bla 2, bla 3}, head 2 : {blo 1, blo 2, blo 3, blo 4}, head 3 :{blu 1 , blu 2}
```

or something like that

One of my attemps

```
for line in open('file.txt'):
block_dict = {}
block = []
ck_nm = [blk_nm for blk_nm in data if line.startswith(blk_nm)]
if ck_nm:
    block_dict[ck_nm[0]] = block = [] 

else:
    block.append(line)
```

but it returns only a lot of empty lists.
I also tried to make a dictionary, by matching head X and take columns in the file but since they are not ordered it returns me something like this

```
head 1 : {bla 1, blu 2, blo 3}, head 2 : {bla 1, bla 2, blo 3, blo 4}, head 3 :{blu 1 , blo 2}
```

Comment: yes, lots of them, i would like to add my script but i dont know if that is possible, i added one of them in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('data', 'r') as f:
    li = f.read()

li =  re.findall(r'(Head.*?\n+.*?)(?:\n+^$|\Z)',li, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

# # split strings on newline
li = list(map(lambda x: re.split('\n+',x),li))
# # create dictionaries
lid = [ {l[0]:{','.join(l[1:])}} for l in li]

pp(lid)

[{'Head 1': {'bla1,bla2,bla3'}},
 {'Head 2': {'blo 1,blo 2,blo 3,blo 4'}},
 {'Head 3': {'blu 1,blu 2'}}]
```

Comment: i've been trying to use this but since i am actually reading a text file and even i turned it to string, i am not able to use this answer (which i think is the right one) i think due to the space between Head X and the next string (i edited the question) and it just prints ['Head 1','Head 2','Head 3']

Comment: @CeDurán no, problem, I have changed it to work from file. will update now.

Comment: hello, thank you very much for the help, but once i added the line space between 'Head X' and the next string (thats how i edited the question), this does not work anymore and it just returns [{'Head 1': set([''])}, {'Head 2': set([''])}, {'Head 3': set([''])}]

Comment: @CeDurán hopefully you wont be changing input anymore. Take a look.